# Can I submit a previously published paper in a journal to an international conference

Tags: peer-review, conference

I'm currently a Phd student in mathematics and one of the requirements for me get my diplomat is to give a talk in an international conference. I have one previously published paper and I submitted that same paper to an international conference. I've been noticed that the paper has been accepted for "publication" by the conference reviewers. This made me wonder if i'm not doing something wrong here. Because I didn't submit the final published version of the paper (with the journal logo and reference) to the conference, but only an old arxiv version of it. I let the conference organizers know about this in a message. So my question is the following:
Is it fine for me to submit a previously published paper to an international conference?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the conference organizers know that the paper was previously published and still accepted it, then you have successfully overcome the first hurdle. However, if you gave up copyright to the paper when the journal published it, then it is no longer yours to re-published since you no longer hold copyright.

If it is merely a matter of presenting the paper (not republishing it) at the conference then there won't be any issues, but you would be  afoul of the (civil) law in many places if you try to yield rights that you don't hold.

Normally journals and conferences frown on this sort of thing, but it depends on who holds rights and what will happen to the submitted paper. Make sure that everyone, including the journal, is aware of all the details.

One additional detail is that if you gave up copyright when the journal published it, then you may have gotten back a license for some, perhaps many, future uses of the paper. With a broad license you would be fine.

---

Caveat: Don't take this as legal advice as IANAL, but as a suggestion to make sure everyone is informed.

And, I've assumed that the conference is reputable and not predatory. Predatory publishers will publish most things, but you don't want to deal with them.